# Initialize dynamicaly added Xeditable Field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I am trying to add dynmic editable field in dropzone.js thumnail part ? now i know that Xeditable fields added dynamicaly are initialize . i am trying it ion angular

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/2008/

Code:

```
 $scope.addfield = function()
    {
    jQuery('.dropzone').append('<a href="#" editable-text="user.name" onbeforesave"updateUser()">KKKKKKKKKK</a>');    
    };
```

After click on add Xeditable field , a new field is added but it is not getting initialize.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `jQuery` to add new xeditable elements. Make use of angular's scope and digest mechanism. First we need an array as a model, which you should iterate over and dynamically add new `editable-text` directive elements in DOM, letting angular do its job and compile new added directives at the right time.

See below some code snippets which may give you a start:

**JS:**

```
// Holds your collection model.
$scope.items = [];

// [...]

var addNewItem = function() {
    $scope.items[$scope.items.length] = { name: 'name' + new Date().getTime(), label: 'New Label' };
}

// [...]

$scope.addfield = function() {
    //jQuery('.dropzone').append('<a href="#" editable-text="user.name" onbeforesave"updateUser()">KKKKKKKKKK</a>'); => don't do it this way!
    addNewItem();
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
    <a class="spacer" href="#" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-bind="item.label + '-' + $index" editable-text="item.name" onbeforesave="updateUser()"></a>
</div>
```

Have a look at this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolaeolariu/gW6pp/2/).

Comment: I cant insert from controller as i need to add it with dropzone thumbnail .on success event i am appending editable field so how do i initialize them, myDropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {     file.previewElement.appendChild("<a href='#' editable-text='user.name' onbeforesave ='updateUser()'>Hello</a>");});